# Find the image of the point $(1,3,4)$ on the plane $2x-y+z+3=0$.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> Find the image of the point $(1,3,4)$ on the plane $2x-y+z+3=0$.

Let the image be $(a,b,c)$.

Equation of the line joining $(1,3,4)$ and  $(a,b,c)$ is $(a-1,b-3,c-4)$  and it will be parallel to the plane given.

Now we have $\dfrac{a-1}{2}=\dfrac{b-3}{-1}=\dfrac{c-4}{1}=k\implies a=2k+1,b=-k+3,c=k+4$.

Since  $(a,b,c)$ lies on the plane so we get $k=-1$.

Hence the point will be $(-1,4,3)$.

But the answer is not coming .Where am I wrong??

Comment: What do you mean by image?

Comment: @gimusi My guess would be the orthogonal projection of the point, but New_User is staying mum so far.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=a(1,3,4)$ then

$$2a-3a+4a+3=0\implies a=-1$$

thus $$P=(-1,-3,-4)$$

Comment: Can you explain how you are  obtaining P here?

Comment: I’ve asked a clarification about was intended by image, here I’m assuming that image is OP multiple of (1,3,4)